# Android: ImageView in the center of landscape activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a very stupid problem.

I can't set an ImageView in the center of landscape acitivity.

I have an image only in the left-center and up-center of activity.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:background="@drawable/load_bg"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/running_animation"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuu're missing the `android:gravity="center"` for the LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/load_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/running_animation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_gravity="center"